# MVC4 Error-No route in the route table matches

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to programming with C# and MVC4 the error happens at

```
@{ 
  Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); 
}
```

It is coming back with an error stating that there is no route in the route table matches the supplied values. I have tried searching the internet to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
   <div id="header">
       <div class="title">Bag Labels</div>
   </div>
    <div id="categories">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); }
    </div>
    <div id="content">
         @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the _Layout.cshtml

Here is my NavController.cs

```
using NavisionStore.Domain.Abstract;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace NavisionStore.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class NavController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;

        public NavController(IProductRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }
        public PartialViewResult Menu(string category = null)
        {
            ViewBag.SelectedCategory = category;

            IEnumerable<string> categories = repository.Products
                .Select(x => x.Category)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(x => x);

            return PartialView(categories);  
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my RouteConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace NavisionStore.WebUI
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(null,
                "",
                new { 
                    controller = "Product", action = "List",
                    category = (string)null, page = 1
                }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(null,
                "Page{page}",
                new { controller = "Product", action = "List", category = (string)null },
                new { page = @"\d+" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(null,
                "{category}",
                new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 }
        );

            routes.MapRoute(null,
                "{category}/Page{page}",
                new { controller = "Product", action = "List" },
                new { page = @"\d+" }
        );

            routes.MapRoute(null, "{contoller}/{action}");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ProductController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using NavisionStore.Domain.Abstract;
using NavisionStore.Domain.Entities;
using NavisionStore.WebUI.Models;



namespace NavisionStore.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;
        public int PageSize = 1;

        public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            this.repository = productRepository;
        }

        public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
        {
            ProductsListViewModel ViewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
            {
                Products = repository.Products
                .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
                .OrderBy(p => p.Id)
                .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize),
                 PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                {
                    CurrentPage = page,
                    ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                    TotalItems = repository.Products.Count()
                },
                CurrentCategory = category
            };

            return View(ViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your routing rules

Comment: Do you have a 'Menu' action in a NavController?

Comment: as @MikeSW said, copy paste your routing rules to the post. That would probably be in class **Application.RouteConfig**

Comment: As you are new to C# and MVC4 you might not know where the routes are set-up. Goto to your Global.asax file and you'll find the routes in the RegisterRoutes method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following routes from your routing config:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
     "",
     new { 
        controller = "Product", action = "List",
        category = (string)null, page = 1
    }
);


routes.MapRoute(null, "{contoller}/{action}");
```

Also, the following routes are likely not doing what you are expecting, as each one is actually returning the same controller/action for each matching url. I recommend removing them.

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
            "Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List", category = (string)null },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(null,
            "{category}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 }
    );

        routes.MapRoute(null,
            "{category}/Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List" },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
    );
```

They could be replaced with the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Page",
   "Product/List/{category}/{page}",
   new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = UrlParameter.Optional },
   new { page = @"\d*" }
);
```

Finally, add names to all of your routes, not `null`. Currently, the only one you have named is "default".

In the end, you should be at a much simpler routing configuration for what you are trying to do:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

// matches:
// product/list/unicorns
// product/list/carrots/15
routes.MapRoute(
   "Page",
   "Product/List/{category}/{page}",
   new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = UrlParameter.Optional },
   new { page = @"\d*" } //<-- note the asterisk here
);

routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "Product", action = "List",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
}
```

Comment: I just changed all my code in my question to what it tells me to use from my example in the book. Please look at my code again and tell me what you think is wrong.

Comment: You have a mispelled 'controller' on the last route. Also, the ```string category = null``` in the Menu action may be an issue; try removing it and hardcoding category as a test. I'm unsure what book you are reading, but it follows some non-standard ways of doing things. Not to say that it is incorrect, just that for a beginner its going to be confusing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I have read my code for a month now and did not see the spelling error I cannot believe I missed it. I also had other programmers look at my code and they did not see that error. Thank you again I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

> Html.RenderAction

so rather try

```
public ActionResult Menu(string category = null)
{
    // Your controller code.

    return View(categories);  
}
```

instead of

```
public PartialViewResult Menu(string category = null)
{
    // Your controller code.

    return PartialView(categories);  
}
```

it also looks like you are missing your default route mapping

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "[Your default controller name goes here]", 
    action = "[Your default action name goes here]", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

**Update**

I don't know if all those routing rules that is specified in your RouteConfig.cs file is needed. Keep it as simple as possible, for example

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", 
        action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**Update**

Your Menu action is expecting a category parameter, so you will have to pass it one, or setup a proper route mapping. So change

```
@{ 
    Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); 
}
```

to

```
@{ 
    Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav", new {category = null}); 
}
```

Comment: User65439 I have just tried your answer and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Hi, it also looks like you are missing a default route mapping. I updated my answer.

Comment: HI, I have just added the default route and the program runs and just sits there with no error and just keeps spinning. I update my routeconfig.cs to show you how it looks now with the new code. Did I add the route correctly?

Comment: Also I updated the Navcontroller.cs to show you how mine looks

Comment: Do you need all those other routing rules? You should simply need the routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}") line and the default routing rule

Comment: I am following an example in a book and it tells me to use all the routing rules.

Comment: MVC will by default only provide you with the default routing rule. You should only add additional rules as and when needed.

Comment: I am following a program example in a book and it does tell me to use all the routes.

Comment: Ok, I can't see anything else wrong. Do the book explain why you have to use all the other routes?

Comment: It says that "/" leads to lists the first page of production from all categories. /Page2 leads to list the specified page(in this case, page 2), showing items from all categories. /Soccer leads to show the first page of items from a specific category(in this case, the soccer category). /Soccer/page2 leads to show the specified page(in this case, page 2) of items from the specified category (in this case soccer). /Anything/Else leads to call the Else action method on the Anything controller.

Comment: Ok then I guess you have to use all of them. It seems like your routing problem was solved and that the problem is now with your ProductController's List action.

Comment: I just added my productController

Comment: What happens when you debug the code of the controller action? Do you get values for the passed parameters? Do you get proper values from your executed linq query?

Comment: When I debug it goes to  @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); } in the _Layout.cshtml and I get an "Error- InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user Code. No route in the route table matches the supplied values."

Comment: Your menu method is expecting a category parameter, so you would have to pass it one using Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav", new {category = null}) or you will have to setup a proper route mapping for it. Have a look at my updated answer

Comment: I just changed my renderaction and am now receiving this error HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: Ok this sounds like an IIS problem, can you browse to a normal view? What I mean by this is, can you create just a simple view and browse to it?

Comment: I just opened an old project and it opened fine

Comment: It's difficult to help you here, there is a lot that can cuase this error, I suggest that you search the web for HTTP Error 403.14, MVC

Comment: Thank you for all your help you have been kind. Charlie Brown has resolved a stupid error on my part. I misspelled "controller" on the last route as "controller". I feel like and idiot, I have missed this spelling error for a month now. Thanks for your help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a piece of HTML on every page you can use **partial view** like this:

```
@Html.Patial("_Menu")
```

instead of

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); }
```

Here **_Menu** is name of partial view **_Menu.cshtml** (should be placed in Views/Shared)

**UPDATE 1**

If you need pass some object (lets say *collection*) to the partial view just specify it as second parameter:

```
@Html.Patial("_Menu", collection)
```

*collection* object will be your model in **_Menu.cshtml** view, so you can use it as usual:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>

<select>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <option>@item</option>
}
</select>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Also your routes rules are too weird. Why don't you use default routing only:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

This will allow you to call your action like this:

- **.../nav/menu**
- **.../product/list**
- **.../** which will equals to **.../product/list** since default controller was set to **ProductController** and default action was set to **List** method.

Any way in route rule you always have to specify **unique** name and template. But you are passing empty string as rule name - it's wrong. You should replace whole your **RouteConfig.cs** as @user65439 mentioned in his answer.

Comment: I just changed all my code in my question to what it tells me to use from my example in the book. Please look at my code again and tell me what you think is wrong

Comment: Charlie Brown has resolved a stupid error on my part. I misspelled "controller" on the last route as "controller". I feel like and idiot, I have missed this spelling error for a month now. Thanks for your help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Charlie Brown has resolved a stupid error on my part. I misspelled "controller" on the last route as "controller". I feel like and idiot, I have missed this spelling error for a month now. Thanks for your help I appreciate it.